# Ansible fech failed: "msg": "checksum mismatch"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to copy a file from remote host to local host. Therefore, I use fetch module of ansible in my playbook:

```html
  - name: sync xml file
    fetch:
      src: "{{ workplace }}/cpp/{{ project }}-cppcheck.xml"
      dest: "{{ result_path }}/{{ project }}-cppcheck.xml"
      flat: yes
```

The file path of remote host is "{{ workplace }}/cpp/{{ project }}-cppcheck.xml", and the local dest path is "{{ result_path }}/{{ project }}-cppcheck.xml". The permission of directory {{ result_path }} in local host is 777. But there are something wrong while running the playbook:

```html
fatal: [10.11.21.11]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "checksum": null, 
    "dest": "/home/fish/MOBILE-cppcheck.xml", 
    "file": "/data/cpp/MOBILE-cppcheck.xml", 
    "md5sum": null, 
    "msg": "checksum mismatch", 
    "remote_checksum": "49c9e966dae54b33623708d9bf5fc2ze5a34e865", 
    "remote_md5sum": null
}
```

The size of MOBILE-cppcheck.xml is 4.0k. The version of Ansible is v2.5
I don't know how to fix it. Is there any advice?

Comment: Can you please run it using debug mode and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file/directory already exists on the Ansible host in the destination path